# How to force a GSON deserialization exception when a field is not present without a custom deserialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I want to be able to check if a certain field is present in my response, and in case it is not present I would like to get an exception.

is there a way to force a GSON deserialization to throw an exception when a field is not present without a custom deserialization?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163193) and [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-design-document)?

Answer (score 0):

[Gson optional and required fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626690/gson-optional-and-required-fields)

I've done something like this in the past.  Registering a TypeAdapter seems to be a decent solution